# Unit test for string value

Tags: java, unit-testing

This test fails:

```
String validString = new String("12345.78");  
myClass.setStringValue(validString);  
assertEquals( "testSetStringValue: " + validString, validString, myclass.getStringValue() );
```

because, I assume, even though `validString` and the return value from `myclass.getStringValue()` contain the same contents `12345.78`, they are different objects.

How do I test for them containing the same thing?

Comment: which testing framework you are using? Also post code for setStringValue and getStringValue methods

Comment: Aside from the fact that equals is indeed the right way to go, what makes you think the return value will refer to a different object? Are you deliberately doing something funky within setStringValue?

Comment: Is the problem that the test fails, or that you want to test for "same" object instead of equals?

Comment: Note: it is never necessary to do `new String("...")`. Just use the string literal directly: `String validString = "12345.78";`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`assertEquals()` will use `equals()` for the comparison, so your test is OK. If you want to test that some object instance is the same as some other, you can use `assertSame()`

see [JUnit doc](http://junit.sourceforge.net/doc/cookbook/cookbook.htm) for more infos.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `assertSame`. But I don't think it makes sense, because it doesn't agree with String contract. Any of your code should not assume strings are `==`, it must rely on that they are `equal`.